# Can the universe have had a beginning and have not had a beginning?

Tags: logic, universe, eternity

I don't know if this question belongs on the physics SE or here.

It's a very simple question however it may have a complex answer, if at all.

The apparent proposition in the question appears contradictory.

However it could be the truth.

Could that proposition be the truth and if so how?

Or rather has that question been philosophically addressed?

Comment: In philosophy, that would be called a contradiction, and almost all philosophers have held that contradictions are always false.

Comment: I think there is a way to interpret the claim as being non-contradictory. The same way we can say that 1 second passed and also 2 seconds passed ( as time is relative) - it may be possible to say something is the begining of the universe ( occuring at time 0) and that something is not the begining of the Universe. We just need that order of causation to be relative.

Comment: Maybe, the begining of the Universe started with 2 relatively causual events A and B. And by relative causation from the perspective of B, A causes B. And From the perspective of A, B caused A.

Comment: can a circle/sphere/ring/loop have a beginning and have no beginning(/end)...? looks like so! at least the mentioned have some "sense/approximation", radius, center...

Answer (score 1):

According to the SEP article on dialetheism, in the [section on the topic relative to the history of Western philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/#DialWestPhil):

> According to Kant, at least in one way of resolving the antinomies [including the antinomy of the world's beginning/non-beginning], the fallacy lies in treating the world as a whole as an object—in mistaking a subjective “condition”, as Kant says, for an objective reality. ... [But on] a dialetheic interpretation, contrary to what Kant held, the Kantian antinomies are not a *reductio* of the illusions of reason; they are perfectly sound arguments, deducing the dialetheic nature of the world.

Alternatively, "the world has, or has not, a beginning" is not exhaustive: in our more up-to-date physics, the question is further specified as, "Is the world finite and bounded, finite and unbounded, infinite and bounded, or infinite and unbounded?" with the ["finite and unbounded"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/247864/what-does-finite-but-unbounded-universe-mean) option being something like a "wrap-around" world. Modulo time, we might speak of the [Hartle-Hawking state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartle%E2%80%93Hawking_state):

> According to the Hartle–Hawking proposal, the universe has no origin as we would understand it: before the Big Bang, which happened about 13.8 billion years ago, the universe was a singularity in both space and time. Hartle and Hawking suggest that if we could travel backwards in time towards the beginning of the universe, we would note that quite near what might have been the beginning, time gives way to space so that there is only space and no time.

[Another quick summary of the above proposal](https://icjs.us/alternative-proposal-to-the-big-bangs-singularity-theory-the-hartle-hawking-state/#:%7E:text=The%20Hartle%2DHawking%20state%20establishes,shaped%20the%20big%20bang%20event.):

> The Hartle-Hawking state establishes a no-boundary condition for the formation of the universe. Boundaries are hypothetical and pre-existing conditions before the big bang that would have shaped the big bang event.

So those are at least two options for the antinomy of the world's beginning: the dialetheist option, or the reformulated-problem option. (Of course, a third is Kant's, and a fourth is to try to prove that one of the proofs involved in the antinomy of time is flawed.)

Comment: I think this could be improved by noting that many (perhaps all) truthy-sounding dialetheias are just a consequence of words with multiple definitions.

Comment: e.g. Heraclitus' *same river* leverages *same* (contiguous with, similar to) vs *same* (composed of the same parts in the same configuration, differing only in place and time) vs *same* (indiscernible, including place and time), the same way and with as little deeper significance as one might say, "Are both boats well-secured? No, the slow boat is fast, but the fast boat is not fast, it's floating slowly away."

Comment: @gs I think that those who take the antinomy of time to reveal that time's beginning-and-non-beginning is a "real" dialetheia are *trying* to mean the same things by their use of the same words. But I am not a dialethist, for both negation-as-cancellation and explosion-argument reasons, so perhaps I don't understand their point of view very well...

Comment: One can reasonably ask and answer "Are there ways for the geometry of the universe to be, consistent our measurements and models, such that the Big Bang would constitute a coordinate singularity?" See e.g. [arXiv:1810.06789](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06789). You can use multiple definitions for "beginning" to make coordinate singularities look like they both are beginnings (constitute horizons across which you can't describe a trajectory) and aren't beginnings (constitute horizons both sides of which can be meaningfully described).

Comment: Still not a real dialetheia, but a much more interesting question than the obfuscated version that *looks* like a dialetheia.

Comment: @gs Most people would assume that the begining of this universe coincides with the beginning of time and therefore the begining of the universe would be incompatible with eternity. However, what if this universe is just one part of a temporal line of universes that would constitute a whole? Is there any scientific theory that would support this?

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 As regards other universes, there are a few testable hypotheses, a lot of speculation that might eventually produce testable hypotheses, no theories at the moment. However, trying to make even just this universe fit with a notion of time that works the way that we and the people who came up with our common language think of time - let alone other universes - does not appear to be the way that reality works.

Comment: IMO physics needs a whole new category of existence-related verbs to handle what !is1! on the other side of the edge of the particle horizon, what !is1! on the inside of black hole event horizons, what !is2! on the other side of the Big Bang, what !is3! the character of universes generated by our universe, and what !is4! the character of other universes generated by universes that !is2! on the other side of the Big Bang.

Comment: @gs Do you know of any cultures that do not have similar limitations to their reasoning and vocabulary or do you think its world wide ?

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 I don't know. I would guess not.

Answer (score 1):

If it could be true, this means that contradictions can be true, and thus your statement and its negation could be true, as could the statement 'contradictions are acceptable'. In other words, if contradictions, which your statement is, can be true, then they can also be false at the same time, making them self-defeating. So no, both of those statements can not be true simultaneously.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If your halfway through the living room door and the hallway. Are you in the living room and not in the living room, and are you in the hallway and not in the hallway?

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 I don't understand your question. I think from what you're saying, part of you would be in the living room and part would be in the hallway. That's not a contradiction, although its phrasing in natural language could seem that way. That would be more akin to saying part of the universe had a beginning and part didn't. The question asks about the full thing however.

Comment: @edelex It's an example of a dialtheism or a true contradiction. It's when you propose the truth of a statement and its negation, of which my question is, as is the statement, I am in the living room and I am not in the living room. The hallway is not the living room. That example is taken from Wikipedia under dialetheism. I understand the logic of your answer and it seems sound, but will also remark there is a conformal cyclical model of the universe by Roger Penrose that may support the proposition however contradictory it may appear.